# How do you burn transaction fees?

Tags: parachain, transactions, substrate-parachain-template

For a transaction fee implementation, i would like to burn 40% of transaction fees, send 30% to treasury and 30% to collators. Which pallet do can i use to do this?

Answer (score 4):

What you are looking for is the `transaction-payment` pallet.
The functions `withdraw_fee` and `correct_and_deposit_fee` of its `CurrencyAdapter` handle the fees.
These fees are then handed over to the `OnUnbalanced` handler. This handler is an injected trait function and can be configured by the runtime.
You see how this works when analyzing the [on_unbalanceds](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/7e4afecf44f066292fb74eeb895940bc597b3481/runtime/common/src/impls.rs#L45) function in the common Polkadot runtime.
It looks like this:

```rust
fn on_unbalanceds<B>(mut fees_then_tips: impl Iterator<Item = NegativeImbalance<R>>) {
    if let Some(fees) = fees_then_tips.next() {
        // for fees, 80% to treasury, 20% to author
        let mut split = fees.ration(80, 20);
        if let Some(tips) = fees_then_tips.next() {
            // for tips, if any, 100% to author
            tips.merge_into(&mut split.1);
        }
        use pallet_treasury::Pallet as Treasury;
        <Treasury<R> as OnUnbalanced<_>>::on_unbalanced(split.0);
        <ToAuthor<R> as OnUnbalanced<_>>::on_unbalanced(split.1);
    }
}
```

The entry points for these functions is the signed extension `ChargeTransactionPayment`.
The `pre_dispatch` calls `withdraw_fee` and `post_dispatch` does `correct_and_deposit_fee`.